# Handling Single vs Multidimensional array from API

Tags: php, arrays, api, curl, multidimensional-array

I am using a CURL statement on an API then feeding the xml to an array which sometimes returns a multidimensional array and sometimes not.

```
function api_query($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
    $result = curl_exec($curl); 
    return $result;
}

function xml_to_string($results) {
    // Store XML String in Array
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($results);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    return $array;
}
```

Example:
    Array(
    [Result] => Array(
            [Orders] => Array(
                    [Order] => Array(
                            [0] => Array(
                                    [OrderId] => 2500001103245195815)

```
                        [1] => Array(
                                [OrderId] => 2500001099767553054)
                    )
            )
    )
)

Array (
[Result] => Array(
        [Orders] => Array(
                [Order] => Array(

                        [OrderId] => 2500001103245195815

                    )
            )
    )
)
```

What could I use instead of an if statement like this:

```
if(isset($array["Result"]["Orders"]['Order'][0])) {
    $arrlength = count($array["Result"]["Orders"]['Order']);

    for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++) {
         $OrderId = $array["Result"]["Orders"]['Order'][$row]['OrderId'];
    }

} elseif(if(isset($array["Result"]["Orders"]['Order'])) {
    $OrderId = $array["Result"]["Orders"]['Order']['OrderId'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation I convert the non array case to the more general one and proceed with universal logic that is independent and equal in both cases.
This way the code is much easier to read and support.

Check the example:

```
if (is_array($array["Result"]["Orders"]['Order'])) {
    $tmpArr = $array["Result"]["Orders"]['Order'];
} else {
    $tmpArr[0]['OrderId'] = $array["Result"]["Orders"]['Order'];
}

// Single logic processing
foreach ($tmpArr as $value)
    $OrderId = $value['OrderId'];
    // Do something with the $OrderId
}
```

Comment: @Dan What about what?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this? Taking it a step further

```
foreach ($tmpArr as $value) {
    $OrderId = $value['OrderId'];

    // Do something with the $OrderId
    echo "Order Id: " . $OrderId . "<br/>";

    if(isset($value["LineItems"]["LineItem"][0])) {
         $itemslength=count($value["LineItems"]["LineItem"]);

        for ($item = 0; $item < $itemslength; $item++) {
            $LineItemId = $value["LineItems"]["LineItem"][$item]["LineItemId"];
            echo "&nbsp;" . "Line Item Id: " .  $LineItemId . "<br/>";
        }
    } else {
        $LineItemId = $value["LineItems"]["LineItem"]["LineItemId"];
        echo "&nbsp;" . "Line Item Id: " .  $LineItemId . "<br/></p>";
    }
}
```